# Accessing values inside the model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I would like to access table data inside a relationship method within the model. But when I run an if statement to check if the type is 'item' then it returns:

> Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null

So it isn't recognizing `$this->type`. How would achieve this?

I have tried to use `$this->type` to see if I could check the type in this way but no luck.

```
class PurchasableItem extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['type', 'value', 'amount'];

    function item_data() {
        if($this->type == 'item')
            return $this->hasOne('App\ItemTemplate', 'id', 'value');
    }
}
```

So I want it to return this relationship only if the type of the purchasable item is of value 'item' but when I try to run this I get the following error:

> Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null

Comment: You can't use `$this` inside a relationship when you use eager loading. `$this->type` returns `null` and so `item_data()` returns `null` (as there is no `else` clause).

Comment: Is there another way of checking the object data?

Comment: There is no other way.

Comment: I have found another way to achieve the result I wanted. Thanks @JonasStaudenmeir for trying to help out :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a fix to achieve what I wanted in another way.

I have added 'data' as an attribute to the model with

```
    protected $appends = ['data'];
```

then I mutate the field to include the correct relationship:

```
    public function getDataAttribute()
    {
        if($this->attributes['type'] == 'item') {
            return ItemTemplate::find($this->attributes['value']);
        } else {
            return License::find($this->attributes['value']);
        }
    }
```